# Get Access Token via Single sign on using API atuomation

Tags: javascript, axios, automation, api-authorization

I have login APIs where I need to generate cookies and get an Html form as a response to initiate the login process which will generate a redirect URL in HTML response I need to take it and post a request with the user name then will get an HTML response with redirect URL for entering password and so on till login.

How to automate it using JavaScript API automation?

```js
 const response1 = await axios.post(apiurl1, body1, header1, { withCredentials: true });
```

From `response1` I am getting an HTML form where I am extracting the URL using `const cheerio = require('cheerio');`. Wrote a method to extract the action URL:

```js
let config2 = {
            method: 'post',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: URL,
            headers: { 
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
              'Cookie': await cookievals / here i am getting cookies values 
            },
            data : qs.stringify({
                'username': 'Username@gmail.com' 
              })
          };

const response2 = await axios.post(config2);
```

For the second response, I am always getting 400 bad requests initially after adding the cookie in headers now getting 500 status code.